# WordPress + BrowserSync + Local by Flywheel - CSS & JS Live Reload Workflow not working

Tags: wordpress, browser-sync

I was trying to get this setup to work for a while and there is no support or similar issues over the web. There is actually one closed topic on Local community but no solution at all.

So, my setup is:

- Local by Flywheel server for WordPress
- VS Code with Node installed
- @wordpress/scripts to bundle all my CSS and JS files
- browser-sync to live reload

Here is my .json file:

```
{
  "name": "mywebsite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "live": "npm-run-all --parallel sync start",
    "sync": "browser-sync start -p 'mywebsite.local' --files '**/*.php' 'build/*.js' 'build/*.css'",
    "build": "wp-scripts build",
    "start": "wp-scripts start",
    "dev": "wp-scripts start",
    "devFast": "wp-scripts start",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@wordpress/scripts": "*",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.9",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5"
  }
}
```

So, the Browser Sync starts nicely in the command line, when starting it opens a new browser windows with this Error below.
There is nothing in the Local's log as they advice on this error screen.

[image]

Do anyone encounters similar problems and have the knowledge how to fix that?
I would be super grateful for any hints, walkarounds or solutions or maybe someone can share the other simple setup ideas to achieve the live reload functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, it comes from the combination of npm-run-all and browser-sync. Instead of using npm-run-all, I used browser-sync as a webpack plugin.

1. Install `browser-sync-webpack-plugin`

```html
npm install browser-sync-webpack-plugin -D
```

2. Then add `browser-sync-webpack-plugin` as plugin in your `webpack.config.js` file. As you use `@wordpress/scripts`, your config will be :

```js
const defaultConfig = require( '@wordpress/scripts/config/webpack.config' );
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin')
 
module.exports = {
    ...defaultConfig,
    plugins: [
        ...defaultConfig.plugins,
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
          // browse to http://localhost:3000/ during development,
          // ./public directory is being served
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 3000,
          proxy: 'http://YOURDOMAIN.local/'
        })
    ]
};
```

Take care to replace `YOURDOMAIN`.

3. Now when you run :

```html
npm start
```

`browser-sync` will be automatically launched.

Comment: OMG! @arnaudpf you are a life saver! It works perfectly for what I need, many thanks now my work will be much faster than before! Once again a huge THANKS!

Comment: is there any way to auto reload PHP files? At the moment with this setup only JS and CSS is automatically reloaded after change is made and I can't find the way to do this. All I found is that BrowserSync needs `<body>` tags where in WordPress all files are split into the parts, so header and footer loads from separate files and there will not be the way to have `<body>` tag on every PHP page.

Comment: Sorry but I finally decided not to use browserify due to performance issues.
Your problem is normal because webpack does not bundle php files.

If you use vscode, I advise you to use the vscode live server extension with the chrome extension that goes with it. It offers better performance and works very well with all types of files.

You will have to enter these settings in the chrome extension panel: 
Actual Server Address:
http://YOURDOMAIN.FIRST_LEVEL_DOMAIN/

Live Server Address:
http://127.0.0.1:5500/

Comment: Ok thanks, is the LiveServer a solution you are using right now? I tried this but I was always loosing connection. The best solution is probably a webpack HRM but it is very hard to configure and I'm not at this level yet. I have gone through the course when we was using HRM but that was for traditional website not for the WordPress but the flow is super fast just instant refresh without actuall browser reload. I don't thing that there is anything better than HRM but not for me, not this level yet.